# Weird division results (C++ / Xcode)

Tags: c++, xcode, division

I'm kinda new here, so please forgive me if I'm doing something wrong. I did a little search before posting this but got no results. So on to the topic: I was getting an error when an AI agent was behaving strangely, so I drafted a few `printf`'s to take a look at what was going on.

It turned out to be a wrong result of a simple division:

```
#define WORLD_HEIGHT 42
#define VIEWPOINT_CONSTANT 9

printf ("%d/%d=%d\n", WORLD_HEIGHT, VIEWPOINT_CONSTANT, WORLD_HEIGHT/VIEWPOINT_CONSTANT);
```

Output:

```
42/9=6
```

Then I did the following just to check the compiler etc.:

```
printf ("%d/%d=%d\n", 42, 9, 42/9);
```

Output:

```
42/9=4
```

Not sure if this is an Xcode bug or something in C++ (though I doubt it's the latter, then again the former is pretty unlikely too). In order to make sure I wasn't overlooking anything, I even put the constants themselves in the `printf`'s.

If anyone has a clue as to what may be the cause of this problem or how to solve it (while still keeping the `#define`'s instead of replacing them with numbers), it would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: I can't reproduce `42/9=6`

Comment: What version of Xcode and what command line options are you using ? Also is the real code, or have you simplified your definitions of `WORLD_HEIGHT` and `VIEWPOINT_CONSTANT` perhaps ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that you're not showing us real code and that what you actually have is something like this:

```
#define WORLD_HEIGHT 42
#define VIEWPOINT_CONSTANT 8+1

printf ("%d/%d=%d\n", WORLD_HEIGHT, VIEWPOINT_CONSTANT, WORLD_HEIGHT/VIEWPOINT_CONSTANT);
```

This will give the result you are seeing because `42/8+1` is not the same as `42/9` - it's evaluated as `(42/8)+1`, which is `5+1` and so you will get a value of `6` rather than `4`. This can be fixed by using parentheses to enforce the required order of evaluation, i.e.

```
#define VIEWPOINT_CONSTANT (8+1)
```

or better still, use a more appropriate method for defining constants rather than preprocessor macros, e.g.

```
const int WORLD_HEIGHT = 42;
const int VIEWPOINT_CONSTANT = 8+1;
```

(Note that the problem goes away with the above declarations and parentheses are no longer required.)

Lessons we have learned today:

- always use parentheses in `#define`s (or better yet use `const`, since this is 2013, not 1983)
- always post real code on StackOverflow !

Comment: or someone who has fixed this in other people's code more than once. ;-)

Comment: @PaulR Thank you for the reply, but that's really not the case. The defines are actually those numbers in the original post, with no operations (therefore no operator precedence issues) going on at all. The code I'm not showing actually is a few thousand lines throughout several headers and source files, but since we're talking about constant definitions I felt free to omit a great part of it. There's nothing that could accidentally change the value of a defined symbol, right? (Then again, even if there were anything like this, the printf would have got it...)

Comment: OK, if that's the case then you need to run the source through the preprocessor and look at the generated code. You can do this with `g++ -E ...` or there is a menu command (`Preprocess` or similar) in most versions of Xcode (its presence and exact name is different for different versions of Xcode).

Comment: OMG nevermind, I just rechecked the definitions header. I seem to have changed those symbols and forgotten. You were right, there was indeed an operation there. I'm sorry, this whole post could have been avoided. :( Edit: Is there a "solved" tag or anything? Once again thank you for your input!

Comment: No problem - you've already flagged the answers as "accepted" so there's no need to do anything else - glad it's all fixed now!